# Is it possible to make the return string of a javascript function into the text for a button in a html page?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently producing a web application that pulls data from the google calendar API, I want to be able to output the return of a JavaScript function as the text for a button in html. 
The code below is pseudo if you like to give a bit more insight into the program, all help is appreciated. (First question on stack overflow, sorry if its not structured properly).

JavaScript

```
function listUpcomingEvents() {
  gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
    'calendarId': 'primary',
    'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
    'showDeleted': false,
    'singleEvents': true,
    'maxResults': 1,
    'orderBy': 'startTime'
  }).then(function(response) {
    var events = response.result.items;
    if (events.length > 0) {
      for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {

        var s = event.summary;
        var ebuttons = function(s){
          return s;
        }
        var str = String(s);

        if (!when) {
          when = event.start.date;
        }
        return (str) //This is the string I want to have as the buttons text 
                       in html
      }
    } else {
      appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
    }
  });
}
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="content">

<button onclick="location.href='#survey'"> listUpcomingEvents()</button>

</div>
```

So just in the "listUpcomingEvents()" part of the button, I want that to be the return value of the JavaScript function.

I'm open to solutions that involve creating a button in the JavaScript alternatively but am new to JavaScript so am still learning how to do these sorts of things.

Thanks!

Comment: Give the button an ID, then use `document.getElementById("buttonid").textContent = str;`

Comment: You can't return a value from an asynchronous function. And if you return inside a `for` loop, the loop ends.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much, this worked perfectly. Thank you for informing me about the for loop ending too, that's also useful!